# while loop date convertion in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am having issues getting this while statement to work. I would like to convert the date format "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYYmmdd" (i.e. `2011-10-04` -> `20111004`).

```
date -d 2011-03-19 +"%Y%m%d"
```

works in command line but not in the while loop script.

The result from while loop:
The below produces:

```
2011-03-17
date: invalid date `+%Y%m%d'

2011-03-10
date: invalid date `+%Y%m%d'

2010-07-07
date: invalid date `+%Y%m%d'
```

`test.txt` contains below sample lines:

```
"2014-09-08T01:49:31Z"
"2014-01-30T03:41:41Z"
"2012-05-23T16:08:45Z"
"2012-05-04T10:16:04Z"
"2012-04-05T15:27:40Z"
```

```
#!/bin/bash

while read QUERYDATE
do
  echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
  echo $(date -d $QUERYDATE_CONVERT +"%Y%m%d")
done < test.txt
```

Comment: The below answers are probably more in the spirit of what you're trying to do, but unless you're eventually doing something fancier, wouldn't a simple `tr -dc - < test.txt` be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `QUERYDATE_CONVERT` is never defined.

Replace:

```
echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
```

With:

```
QUERYDATE_CONVERT=$(echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g')
```

This will result in the output:

```
20140908
20140130
20120523
20120504
20120405
```

#### Where did the error message come from?

Consider the command:

```
date -d $QUERYDATE_CONVERT +"%Y%m%d"
```

Now, if `QUERYDATE_CONVERT` is undefined, then, after variable substitution, the above becomes:

```
date -d +"%Y%m%d"
```

Thus, the string `+"%Y%m%d"` is now the argument to the `-d` option. Since no such date exists, `date` displays the error message:

```
date: invalid date `+%Y%m%d'
```

#### Notes

- Because the shell uses upper case names for its variables, it is best practice to use mixed or lower case names for shell variables.  This assures that you don't accidentally overwrite something important.
- Since the substitutions used are here are simple, it is possible to replace the call to `sed` with shell expansions, as shown by sputnick.
- This may not be true of your ultimate application but, in the script as shown, the line:

  ```
  echo $(date -d $QUERYDATE_CONVERT +"%Y%m%d")
  ```

  can be replaced with:

  ```
  date -d $QUERYDATE_CONVERT +"%Y%m%d"
  ```

#### Alternatives

MarkReed points out that, under `bash`, the pipeline can be replaced by a here-string:

```
QUERYDATE_CONVERT=$(sed 's/"\|T.*//g' <<<"$QUERYDATE")
```

The here-string eliminates a process and, thus, should be more efficient.  As this question is tagged `bash`, this is a good solution here.

Here-strings, however, are not POSIX.  They will not, for example, work under `dash` which is the default `/bin/sh` on debian-like systems.  It is still possible to eliminate the extra process while keeping POSIX compatibility if a here-document is used:

```
QUERYDATE_CONVERT=$(sed 's/"\|T.*//g' <<EOF
$QUERYDATE
EOF
)
```

Comment: I would prefer a here-string there: `QUERYDATE_CONVERT=$(sed 's/"\|T.*//g' <<<"$QUERYDATE")`

Comment: @MarkReed Good suggestion.  The here-string is a nice form and does have the advantage of eliminating a process.  The disadvantage, which is important in many environments that I use, is that it is not POSIX.  If one really wants to avoid that extra process, a third choice, which is POSIX, is a here-document.

Comment: @MarkReed I updated the answer with here-string and here-doc forms.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash's [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read querydate; do
    querydate="${querydate%T*}"
    echo "$(date -d "${querydate//\"/}" +"%Y%m%d")"
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read QUERYDATE
    do
    echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
    echo $(date -d $QUERYDATE_CONVERT +"%Y%m%d")
    done < test.txt
```

This piece of code is affecting your script

```
echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
```

This just **print** the date that was taken out from the string (sed output)  but does not store it.Therefore the  variable `$QUERYDATE` remains the same

```
"2014-09-08T01:49:31Z"
"2014-01-30T03:41:41Z"
"2012-05-23T16:08:45Z"
"2012-05-04T10:16:04Z"
"2012-04-05T15:27:40Z"
```

To fix this you can try replacing:

```
echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'
```

with:

```
QUERYDATE=`echo $QUERYDATE | sed 's/"\|T.*//g'`
```

Now you will get your desired output since the unformat date is taken modified and re-assigned to the variable QUERYDATE.

OUTPUT

```
20140908
20140130
20120523
20120504
20120405
```